# What is the purpose of --use-npm in create-next-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, next.js

When creating an NextJS app using the CLI, one can choose `--use-npm` when running `npx create-next-app`. When running it without arguments (ie in interactive mode) it doesn't ask about this.

The [help page](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/create-next-app) says

```
  --use-npm
 
    Explicitly tell the CLI to bootstrap the app using npm
```

and if I use it, then it changes `tsconfig.json` to

```
    "paths": {
      "--use-npm": ["./src/*"]
    }
```

instead of

```
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
```

**Question**

What is the purpose of `--use-npm`?

Comment: Is the default to use yarn instead?

Comment: I use npm, and would like to know what this argument does.

Comment: That's what I'm saying: if yarn is the default package manager in a cna bootstrapped app, it would totally make sense to have a cli switch to use npm instead.

Comment: Why does it then change the `paths`  in `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the problem and solution.

The command I ran was

```
npx create-next-app --typescript --tailwind --app --src-dir --import-alias --use-npm --no-eslint
```

which should have been

```
npx create-next-app --typescript --tailwind --app --src-dir --import-alias '@/*' --use-npm --no-eslint
```

For some reason `create-next-app` doesn't have `--no-import-alias` which would have been very useful.

Answer (score 2):

`create-next-app` has this line in the [source code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/create-next-app/index.ts#L140) to determine whether to use `npm`, `pnpm` or `yarn` based on the provided flags:

```js
const packageManager = !!program.useNpm
  ? 'npm'
  : !!program.usePnpm
  ? 'pnpm'
  : !!program.useYarn
  ? 'yarn'
  : getPkgManager()
```

If you don't use an explicit flag then the `getPkgManager` function looks to see if "yarn" or "pnpm" exists in the `npm_config_user_agent` environment variable and defaults to `npm` otherwise. ([source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/create-next-app/helpers/get-pkg-manager.ts))

So interactive mode is just defaulting to `npm`.